# how does fields_for know how many fields to create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I guess I'm a little confused on how fields_for works. I have an action with this:

```
  3.times { @submitted_quiz.submitted_answers.build }
```

if I write a `form_for` like this in the associated view:

```
<%= form_for(@submitted_quiz) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :quiz_id, :value => @quiz.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @quiz.name %>

<%= f.fields_for (:submitted_answers) do |ff| %>

  <%= ff.label :content, "Answer" %><br />
    <%= ff.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %>
<% end %>


<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

how does `fields_for` know to run three times?

Comment: It counts how many submitted_answers are associated with @submitted_quiz and does it that many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will simply check how many submitted_answers your submitted_quiz has and generate appropriate number of fields ( one for each answer obviously ).